# wxPython scrollbar doesn't stick

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython, scrollbar

I've been playing with this [cookbook example](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/ScrollingPlot) to make a scrollable matplotlib plot with wxPython.  However, when I run this code on my Windows 7 machine at work, the scrollbar doesn't seem to work properly.  In particular, if I click and drag it to a position, it does update the plot, but then the scrollbar moves back its starting position, instead of staying put.  I'm curious if anyone has an idea what's going on here.  FWIW, this code worked fine when I ran it on my Linux Mint 14 machine at home.

Right now, I'm trying to fix it by using a wx.ScrolledWindow or a wx.lib.scrolledpanel instead of adding the scrollbar directly to the canvas as in the example.  I was also considering using a slider instead of a scrollbar

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Programing Windows, Fifth Edition](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/microsoft-windows/9780735642225/an-exercise-in-text-output/scroll_bars) (emphasis mine)...

> When you use scroll bars within your program, you share responsibility
>   with Windows for maintaining the scroll bars and updating the position
>   of the scroll bar thumb. These are Windows' responsibilities for
>   scroll bars:
>
> - Handle all processing of mouse messages to the scroll bar.
> - Provide a reverse-video "flash" when the user clicks the scroll bar.
> - Move the thumb as the user drags the thumb within the scroll bar.
> - Send scroll bar messages to the window procedure of the window containing the scroll bar.
>
> These are the responsibilities of your program:
>
> - Initialize the range and position of the scroll bar.
> - Process the scroll bar messages to the window procedure.
> - **Update the position of the scroll bar thumb.**
> - Change the contents of the client area in response to a change in the scroll bar.

...so somewhere in `OnScrollEvt()` method, you'll need call [`SetScrollPos()`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Window-class.html#SetScrollPos) with something like...

```
self.canvas.SetScrollPos(wx.HORIZONTAL, event.GetPosition(), True)
```

Comment: Perfect, a quick and easy fix.  Thanks very much :)

Comment: @JohnEdwardson Fortunately, I faced exactly the same problem in an app I wrote recently, so this was a no-brainer for me. :)